# Create components with custom refs and access it later

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-ref

I want to create components dynamically with custom Refs , and I want to use those refs and use with functionalities like measure() etc.

I created following code

```
var elems = [];
const CarousalLoop = (props) => { 
  
  
  var links = [
    { name: 'america' },
    { name: 'canada' },
    { name: 'norway' },
    { name: 'bahamas' }
  ];
  
   links.forEach((val, index) => {
    elems[val.name]=  useRef(null);
  });
  
 const listItems = links.map((link) =>
 <CustomCarousel ref={elems[link.name]}  category={link.name}/>
    );
    return (
     <View style={{backgroundColor:"white"}}>

       {listItems}
     </View>
    );
}
```

For example I want to access the compenents using elems["america"] and use it later.
but I get following error.

```
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

1. Yes, React refs need to be forwarded when using functional components.
2. You can't use the `useRef` hook within the loop.

## Solution

Fix creating the refs. Use a React ref to hold an array of created refs, and pass them by mapped index.

```
const CarousalLoop = (props) => {

  const linkRefs = useRef([]);
  
  const links = [
    { name: 'america' },
    { name: 'canada' },
    { name: 'norway' },
    { name: 'bahamas' }
  ];

  linkRefs.current = links.map((link) => linkRefs.current[link.name] ?? createRef());
  
  const listItems = links.map((link) => (
    <CustomCarousel
      key={link.name}
      ref={linkRefs.current[link.name]}
      category={link.name}
    />
  ));

  return (
    <View style={{backgroundColor:"white"}}>
      {listItems}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Forward the ref. This is done by wrapping the `CustomCarousel` in `React.forwardRef`.

```
const CustomCarousel = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  // component logic
  // attach `ref` to DOMNode if necessary or access in `useImperativeHandle` hook
  ...
});
```

Later when you want/need to access a specific ref, reference it by is key and then access the current value.

```
linkRefs.current['america']?.current
```

Comment: Does this have custom name to refs ?  I see we are just passing index to refs.

Comment: also can you give some more example what should be inside CustomCarousel ?  I use rect native.

Comment: @Graciewilliams Sorry, I don't understand your question. About the `CustomCarousel`, is that not a component of yours? Are you asking what to attach the ref to or how to access it within `CustomCarousel` component?

Comment: Right now I am using <CarousalLoop/> inside my main app and it works fine ,, I want to access it later by linkRefs["america"] , can you please give example for that.

Comment: Oh, I see, so you want something more like `ref={linkRefs.current[link.name]}`?

Comment: Yes please see my question , I was trying to set name with custom name..

Comment: Hi , I got undefined  error , So can I place const linkRefs = useRef([]);  outside the CarousalLoop function ? I actually want to access these components in another onscroll function in same page.

Comment: @Graciewilliams Maybe. They could be declared wherever the `links` array is defined, and then passed as a prop to `CarousalLoop`. It seems you haven't posted all the relevant code and explained well enough what you are wanting/trying to do. What are you really trying to use these refs for? This may be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Thanks , I just used the refs to View and it solved the issue.